# Spring boot hibernate auto scan entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm fairly new to spring boot and trying to build a spring boot application with Java Persistence API + hibernate + mySQL persistence layer. But when I'm trying to fetch all records using, `entityManager.createNamedQuery("SELECT * FROM Student s", Student.class).getResultList()` it is giving me following exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name
>   [SELECT * FROM Student s]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildQueryFromName(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:771)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:869)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:304)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at com.sys.sch.orm.dao.impl.StudentDaoImpl.findAll(StudentDaoImpl.java:30)
>   ~[school-system-orm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]

I'm trying to configure this project without `persistence.xml` or `hibernate.cfg.xml` and trying to use spring boot auto configurations.
I've also added `@EntityScan("com.sys.sch.orm.model")` as most of the readings I've done.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.sys.sch"})
@EntityScan("com.sys.sch.orm.model")
public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Program.class, args);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "student")
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "birth_date")
private Date birthDate;

@CreationTimestamp
private Date dateCreated;

@UpdateTimestamp
private Date dateUpdated;
// getters and setters
}
```

dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>school-system</groupId>
    <artifactId>school-system-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schoolsys?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFhD3.png)

If anyone could show me what's I'm doing here wrong I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between `createNamedQuery()` and `createQuery()`.

`createNamedQuery()` takes the name of a predefined query:

```
@Entity(name = "student")
@NamedQuery(query = "select s from Student s", name = "findAllStudents")
public class Student {
    ...
}
```

This query can then be referenced by its name:

```
Query query = entitymanager.createNamedQuery("findAllStudents");
List<Student> students = query.getResultList();
```

On the other hand, `createQuery()` takes a jpql statement

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select s from Student s");
```

Or more simply

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Student");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now.